# lines not rendering after switching to freeglut

Tags: c++, opengl, line, glut, freeglut

I had a project that i was using glut in - however i went to free glut in order to be able to use

```
glutBitmapCharacter
```

However when I did that what I was using to draw a grid no longer works

```
//This creates the grid 
    for(float f = -1;f<1; f+=0.05){
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        glVertex2f(f,-1);
        glVertex2f(f,1);
        glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        glVertex2f(-1,f);
        glVertex2f(1,f);
        glEnd();
    }
```

Full class:

```
   #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<windows.h>
    #include<GL/glut.h>
    #include<GL/freeglut.h>
    #include<iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include "include/Block.h"
    #include <string>


    using namespace std;

    void drawBitmapText(char *string, float x, float y, float z);
    void reshape(int w, int h);
    void render(void);
    void keyboard(unsigned char c,int x,int y);
    void mouse(int button,int state, int x, int y);


    vector <Block> blockList;
    int screenXSize=800;
    int screenYSize=800;
    int selectedBlockType = 0;
    int main(int argc, char ** argv){


    blockList.push_back(*new Block(0,1,1));

    Block Test = blockList.at(0);
    string s = Test.getName();



    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(screenXSize,screenYSize);
    glutCreateWindow("TITLE");
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();








    }
    void mouse(int button,int state, int x, int y){
        if(button==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON){


        }
         if(button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON){


        }

    }
    void keyboard(unsigned char c,int x,int y){
        if (c==27){
            exit(0);
        }

    }
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h); 
   glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION); 
   glLoadIdentity (); ...

   gluOrtho2D (0.0, (GLdouble) w, 0.0, (GLdouble) h);
}
void drawBitmapText(char *string, float x, float y, float z)
{
    char *c;
    glRasterPos3f(x, y, z);

    for (c=string; *c != '\0'; c++)
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, *c);
    }
}
    void render(void){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    drawBitmapText("CAN YOU READ ME?",200,200,0);




    //This creates the grid 
    for(float f = -1;f<1; f+=0.05){
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        glVertex3f(f,-1);
        glVertex3f(f,1);
        glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        glVertex2f(-1,f);
        glVertex2f(1,f);
        glEnd();
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated

```
    glutSwapBuffers();

    glFlush();
    }
```

However I am able to run the sample  project

```
/*
 * GLUT Shapes Demo
 *
 * Written by Nigel Stewart November 2003
 *
 * This program is test harness for the sphere, cone
 * and torus shapes in GLUT.
 *
 * Spinning wireframe and smooth shaded shapes are
 * displayed until the ESC or q key is pressed.  The
 * number of geometry stacks and slices can be adjusted
 * using the + and - keys.
 */

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>

static int slices = 16;
static int stacks = 16;

/* GLUT callback Handlers */

static void resize(int width, int height)
{
    const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity() ;
}

static void display(void)
{
    const double t = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0;
    const double a = t*90.0;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3d(1,0,0);

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(-2.4,1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutSolidSphere(1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0,1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutSolidCone(1,1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(2.4,1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutSolidTorus(0.2,0.8,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(-2.4,-1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutWireSphere(1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0,-1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutWireCone(1,1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(2.4,-1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutWireTorus(0.2,0.8,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 27 :
        case 'q':
            exit(0);
            break;

        case '+':
            slices++;
            stacks++;
            break;

        case '-':
            if (slices>3 && stacks>3)
            {
                slices--;
                stacks--;
            }
            break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void idle(void)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

const GLfloat light_ambient[]  = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_diffuse[]  = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_position[] = { 2.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f };

const GLfloat mat_ambient[]    = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_diffuse[]    = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_specular[]   = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0f };

/* Program entry point */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("GLUT Shapes");

    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(key);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT,  light_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE,  light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT,   mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE,   mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR,  mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, high_shininess);

    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your grid is being clipped (discarded) by OpenGL because it's outside of the viewing frustum.

In your `reshape` function, you set the region for objects to be *(0, width)* in the *x* direction, and *(0, height)* in the *y* direction with the call to `gluOrtho2D`.  That in itself isn't an issue, but the coordinates you use for your grid is (-1,1).  If you look closely at your window, you'll see the pixel in the lower-left corner lit up.

The fundamental thing you need to do is figure out which space you want to draw into.  With the `gluOrtho2D` you have, you're effectively rendering in window coordinates, and so if you update your grid to render from *[0, width]* as compared to *[-1,1]*, your grid will appear as well as the text.  Conversely, if you want to use the coordinate space of your grid, update the `gluOrtho2D` function to `gluOrtho2D( -1, 1, -1, 1 )`, and update the position you render your text at to be within that square.

One other minor point, there's a primitive type named `GL_LINES`, which will draw a line segment between every two vertices.  In your grid rendering loop, you can be more efficient by writing the loop as

```
glBegin( GL_LINES );
for ( float f = -1; f < 1; f += 0.05 ) {
    glVertex2f( f, -1 );
    glVertex2f( f , 1 );
    glVertex2f( -1, f );
    glVertex2f(  1, f );
}
glEnd();
```

(oh, and in your example, you mix `glVertex2f`, and `glVertex3f` [which is perfectly legal OpenGL], except that in your use of `glVertex3f`, you only provide two parameters causing a syntax error)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer- just as a side note, I had tried something similar to your loop earlier, and it crashed. And this still happens with your version of the loop.

Comment: You're welcome.  As for the loop, are you sure you weren't using the `glVertex*fv` version?  Those functions expect a single, pointer value, so if you pass in a numeric value, you could easily get a crash.